# How to derive the $\Delta$-$Y$ formula for capacitors?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

So, I've found a youtube video that first derives the formula for the resistors and then says the capacitance is the resistance^(-1). I was wondering if that would be the right approach.

Comment: Why do you think they would do that?

Comment: I have no idea, that's why I asked. Here's the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCx-7fzC8Ew&fbclid=IwAR2gxg5EoW2ITVXB_L32CJe2ldpAEIhXI243RgcHi6etWP5QuOCFkaw1YJ8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Alfred Centauri:

I believe what you need is the concept of [electrical impedance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance). The complex impedance of a capacitor is 
$$ Z_C= \frac{1}{j \omega C}, $$
where $j=\sqrt{-1}$, and $\omega$ is the angular frequency at which the circuit is being driven. The derivation for the $\Delta$-$Y$ formula will be identical but with $R$ replaced by $Z_C$.

Edit: What do you know, there's even a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) that says this explicitly.